# Group a dates by range

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I'm struggling with a T-SQL query to partitions/group a dates table into periods. ***A new period is defined as from 16th of a month to 15th the next month***.

So if the table looks like this:

```
2022-05-13
2022-05-14
2022-05-15
2022-05-16
2022-05-17
2022-05-18
2022-05-19
2022-05-20
2022-05-21
2022-05-22
2022-05-23
2022-05-24
2022-05-25
2022-05-26
..
..
```

The expected result would be:

```
2022-05-13   1
2022-05-14   1
2022-05-15   1
2022-05-16   2
2022-05-17   2
2022-05-18   2
2022-05-19   2
2022-05-20   2
2022-05-21   2
2022-05-22   2
2022-05-23   2
2022-05-24   2
2022-05-25   2
2022-05-26   2
..
..
2022-06-15   2
2022-06-16   3
```

I suspect I need a window function here of sorts, but I am very inexperienced with those. Programatically I would loop each date, and lookahead to the period date (16th of next month), but I need this in SQL.

What I have tried is this:

```
WITH T AS
(
SELECT Date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) AS Period
FROM dbo.Dates
WHERE DayOfMonth = 16

)
SELECT D.Date, Period  FROM dbo.Dates D
LEFT JOIN T ON D.Date = T.Date
```

However it is incomplete and will not fill out the null values after the join.

Comment: The answer you want is database dependent.  Which SQL _database_ are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry, it's MS SQL

Comment: Use row_number for all the dates with day = 16 and then lag for everything else.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple using window functions.

You need to subtract 15 days, then get the end of that month.

Then you use `DENSE_RANK` to get the ranking

```sql
SELECT *,
  DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY EOMONTH(DATEADD(day, -15, d.date)))
FROM Dates d;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2a5ae46db6c7f51867773ed757ebd9a3)

| Date | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-05-13 | 1 |
| 2022-05-14 | 1 |
| 2022-05-15 | 1 |
| 2022-05-16 | 2 |
| 2022-05-17 | 2 |
| 2022-05-18 | 2 |
| 2022-05-19 | 2 |
| 2022-05-20 | 2 |
| 2022-05-21 | 2 |
| 2022-05-22 | 2 |
| 2022-05-23 | 2 |
| 2022-05-24 | 2 |
| 2022-05-25 | 2 |
| 2022-05-26 | 2 |